# Script batch - mover diretorio pai e subdiretorio

Tags: windows, script, batch

como crio um **".bat"** para mover todos  os arquivos em especifico ou melhor somente aqueles com  extensão **".txt"** de um diretório e todos seu subdiretórios para outra pasta.

Answer (score 2):

Como não tenho certeza se entendi corretamente, então temos 2 formas de resolver seu problema.

A forma abaixo ira copiar todos os arquivos com a extensão e as subpastas para o destino e criara as mesmas pastas onde estavam os arquivos com a extensão:

**`Solução 1`**

```
xcopy c:\*.txt d:\textos /sy
```

> /s irá torná-lo "recursiva"
>   /y pergunta se deseja substituir.

**`Solução 2`**
Para cada arquivo no diretório `c:\` e subdiretórios `/R` que correspondem ao padrão (`.*txt`) ira colocar o nome do arquivo na variável `%%f`, em seguida, para cada arquivo para o destino `d:\textos`, ou seja, todos arquivos `.*txt` que encontrar não importa a subpasta, ira todos para `d:\textos`, caso houver nome repetido ira substituir.

```
for /R c:\ %%f in (*.txt) do copy %%f d:\textos
```

> /R percorrer subdiretórios.